# Использование __init__.py в современном коде

Tags: python, python-3.x, модули

Надо ли в современном коде добавлять файл `__init__.py` в директорию, из которой собираешься импортировать модули? Или достаточно использовать неявные namespace пакеты?

Comment: Использование инит файла не обязательно, без него тоже будет работать. Инит файл нужен если вы хотите что то в нём сделать, например из под-пакетов/под-модулей импортировать по иерархии выше некоторые символы. Например есть функция f в пакете x.y, можно внутри x пакета создать инит файл где автоматом f символ импортируется в x, так что в итоге у клиента можно будет написать `import x; x.f()`.

Answer (score 3):

**Отвечая на ваш вопрос:**
Файл `__init__.py` требовался в Python 2.X, больше не требуется, предположительно, начиная с Python 3 и выше.

**Также добавлю:**
Вы можете не использовать `__init__.py` либо оставлять его пустым, в таком случае он будет выполнять код инициализации для пакета или устанавливать переменную `__all__`.

Файлы `__init__.py` необходимы, для того, чтобы Python рассматривал каталоги как содержащие пакеты; это делается для того, чтобы предотвратить каталоги с общим именем, например string, от непреднамеренного скрытия допустимых модулей, которые происходят позже (глубже) на пути поиска модуля.

Comment: `предположительно, начиная с Python 3 и выше.` - начиная с 3.3, если быть точным: [PEP 420](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), [What’s New In Python 3.3 - PEP 420: Implicit Namespace Packages](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages)